# How much clearance does a car need when turning a corner?

Tags: automotive-engineering

I am contemplating buying a new car. However, the approach to the underground garage in my apartment has a 90 degree frustrating turn. Given the dimensions of the approach and car, what is the max turn circle for the car to fit the garage and turn?

[image: garage and car dimensions]

[image: more legible dimensions]

given Ackerman steering and the overhanging front part of the car I believe you can use Pythagoreas' theorem to get R min and R max. delta R should be less than the shortest path in the pathway, ie 2.5m. unfortunately the result does not seem plausible. feedback would be greatly appreciated.[image]

Comment: Do you know the maximum wheel deflection? That's kinda important for this.

Comment: But if you have the max wheel deflection then the turn circle would also be given? What I'm looking for is the max turn circle that still would leave the car without scratches.

Comment: What's the car's width? The "table" has it as 2120mm, but the drawing has it as 2200mm.

Comment: For that matter, can you write down all the longitudinal dimensions? I can't read them. As I read them, the length is 5030mm, the distance between axes is 2900mm, the rear distance is 1248mm and the front distance would have to be 882mm, but I'm pretty sure that's not what's written down. What have I misread?

Comment: recent cars are not rectangular in planform, they have round corners at the front, which allows turning-parking in tighter spaces. therefore this question is either a theoretical one (about calculating turn-radius from basic dimensions); or a practical one but lacks important information (real shape of the car, especially at the front side).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is "read the car's data sheet"; there's insufficient information to calculate the answer, and the numbers you'd need to calculate the answer are from the car's data sheet, which would also contain the turning circle of the car anyway.

Comment: Although I agree @EnergyNumbers' arguments, on my opinion these arguments extended with a small explanation, how the turning circle can be calcuated (formulas), could serve as a good quality answer. So I voted for leave open.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers and others - there is more to this question than just "turning circle."  It seems fruitful ground for a discussion of "how to get around a corner optimally and what factors affect it. I known that in turning in a narrow street (we drive on the left) I can optimise a U turn with a swing out right (to near right curb if situation and societal pressures allow), then turn hard left tpo then swing hard right to just miss left curb and turn on hard right lock to right curb (or complete turn in some cases). | In this problem's scenario, assuming that TC is in fact well defined ....

Comment: ... How does TC and and wheelbase and length (or outer dimensions) of vehicle affect its swept area? Is the key assumption on a "square" approach the optimum one - ie I suspect (as a driver of long experience)(and an engineer)  that an optimum approach MAY be 'at X start on right going left at angle Ax (probably full lock) , at Y (probably left wall) turn to right at angle Ay (probably full lock), at Z (probably right wall ) turn left on full lock to negotiate corner. What is the optimum for a given scenariuo. What domensions matter? How ...? Hopefully, inquiring minds want to know

Comment: I've been looking around the web for solutions to this problem and in the end I found the framework for solving problems like this (there had to be one-). The method is called swept path analysis and there are multiple software products doing it-but from what I've seen mostly within the CAD world. I haven't found much info about the theory-the closest is http://hawsedc.com/gnu/turntheo.php.

Comment: The answer depends on how many times you're willing to back up and move forward. Just like with parallel parking, the more times you're willing to go back and forth the tighter a space you can fit through. If you're not willing to back up then the answer is fairly straight forward.

Comment: Assuming I'm not willing to back up-please enlighten me.

Comment: With the dimensions a=2500mm, b=2900mm, W=1670mm, and car length of 5030mm the car would not fit around the corner even if it was on dollies so you could move it any direction you desired... are these dimensions correct?

Comment: Note that I ignored the mirrors, to properly include the mirrors, you'd also need the location of the mirrors relative to the rear axle. (In general the location of the front wheels doesn't matter in this problem. It just contributes to the relation between turning radius and wheel turning angle)

Comment: @Rick - You are quite right. I´ve now measured properly and found a=3.3 , b=5.2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To slightly generalize I'll reform the question slightly.

A ridged 2-D body (car) has a line $l$ that moves with it.
The car can be linearly transformed as long as the instantaneous center of rotation lies along $l$ at least distance $R$ away from a point $c$ that also moves with the car.

In this case point $c$ lies in the center of the rear axle and $l$ lies on the rear axle.

Now imagine the car's domain is limited to a quarter plane with edges $A$ and $B$. It initially is placed against $A$, far from $B$ with $l$ perpendicular to $A$, and the goal is to translate the car so that it is  against $B$ far from $A$ while minimizing the maximum distance from the closest edge.

($A$ and $B$ can be placed a inch away from the actual walls to prevent scratches and allow for non-idealized vehicle movement.)

### Reversals allowed

The solution is to advance the car along $A$ until it is an infinitesimal distance from $B$ (using an infinite turning radius to travel in a straight line) Then rotate about the tightest turning radius until in contact with $B$ Then rotate about the tightest turning radius on the opposite side until back in contact with $A$. This results in linear movement in the opposite direction but rotation in the same direction. These two steps can be repeated (infinitely) until $l$ is perpendicular to $B$ at which point it can advance away from $A$ in a straight line. From a macro perspective this looks like the car sliding along $A$ until it reaches $B$, then rotating while maintaining contact with both walls and finally advancing along $B$. This solution is independent of turning radius but involved infinite reversals.

### No reversals

Now lets further constrain our translations so that center of rotation must be further from $A$ and $B$ than $c$. (This removes the usefulness of backing up)
Now the middle of the optimum strategy is obvious: turn at the maximum turning radius, but how do you minimize the distance to the wall approaching and exiting this strategy?

You remain in contact with the wall.

As you approach the wall and see you're just about to clear it, rather than continuing to turn you can gradually increase the turning radius to remain in contact with the wall. To remain in contact with the wall means the line between the contact point and the center of rotation is perpendicular to the wall.

From this we can get the position of the center of rotation while in the minimum turning radius portion of the turn.

[image: COR possition]

$$D_{rear}=\sqrt{{O_{rear}}^2+(R_{min}+W)^2}$$
$$D_{front}=\sqrt{(O_{front}+WB)^2+(R_{min}+W)^2}$$

This point fully defines the most interesting portion of the turn allowing one to see if any obstacle on the other side would be struck. To clear:

[image: Tight corner diagram]

$$\sqrt{(D_{rear}-b)^2+(D_{front}-a)^2} \leq R_{min}$$

Note that it makes a difference if you're going forward or backward. To see if you'd clear both directions you'd have to test with a and b reversed.

Indeed in the diagram above I've set $a=5.9m$ and $b=3.3m$. In this case it was because while the thick arc defined by drawing and equations above might be the most interesting portion of the curve, it is not going to be the limiting factor when $a$ and $b$ are not flipped. So we need to extend that curve.

The end points can be found using similar triangles, from there, the curve will just be an tangent exponential decay to a distance $W$ from the wall.

[image: Diagram of swept closest point with added exponential sections]

With these curves we can define a function $C$ to tell us whether the vehicle would clear an object placed at $(a,b)$:

$$
C(a,b) =
  \begin{cases} 
      \hfill \sqrt{(D_{rear}-b)^2+(D_{front}-a)^2} \leq R_{min}   \hfill & \text{ if } a \leq a_{check} \text{ and } b \leq b_{check} \\
      \hfill W+W_{rear}e^{\frac{(a_{check}-a)O_{rear}}{(R_{min}+W)W_{rear}}} \leq b   \hfill & \text{ if } a > a_{check} \text{ and } b \leq b_{check} \\
      \hfill W+W_{front}e^{\frac{(b_{check}-b)(O_{front}+WB)}{(R_{min}+W)W_{front}}} \leq a   \hfill & \text{ if } a \leq a_{check} \text{ and } b > b_{check} \\
      \hfill true   \hfill & \text{ if } a > a_{check} \text{ and } b > b_{check} \\
  \end{cases}
$$

Where:

$$a_{check}=D_{front}-O_{rear}\frac{R_{min}}{D_{rear}}$$
$$b_{check}=D_{rear}-(O_{front}+WB)\frac{R_{min}}{D_{front}}$$
$$W_{front}=D_{front}-(R_{min}+W)\frac{R_{min}}{D_{rear}}-W$$
$$W_{rear}=D_{rear}-(R_{min}+W)\frac{R_{min}}{D_{front}}-W$$

Now to solve this system backwards to get the maximum $R_{min}$ that would allow passage requires making a few observations and assumptions. First we'll assume that you want to be able to drive around the corner in ether direction that means we'll swap $a$ and $b$ for whichever scenario is worse. If The front corner is further from the fixed axle than the rear corner (as is the case for all front steering vehicles I know of) then a < b is the tighter scenario.

Then one could use a numerical method to find the $R_{min}$ that gave equality for the second inequality. If $a\geq a_{check}$ then you're done. If not, then find the $R_{min}$ that gives equality for the first inequality.

### Glossary

- $W$ - Width of car
- $WB$ - Wheel Base
- $O_{front/rear}$ - Overhang of the front/rear
- $R_{min}$ - minimum distance between the center of rotation and the car
- $a$ - distance from outside wall to inside corner
- $b$ - distance from outside wall to inside corner

### Plugging in

With the numbers given It turns out that the maximum $R_{min}$ is slightly under $6.6m$

[image: Diagram of car just clearing the corner.]

But you might have to fold the right mirror in.

Comment: WOW- that is one elaborate answer. However, I cannot get the meaning of "The car can be linearly transformed as long as the instantaneous center of rotation lies along l at least distance R away from a point c that also moves with the car." furthermore, quarter plane - what is it? Finally, how did you arrive at the final equation? NB - I had a second look in the garage - this time with a measure. Turns out a- 3.3m, b=5.2m.

Comment: The first quote describes the motion that ackerman steering allows in a rigorous manner. Basically, for every steering wheel position, the car would move in a circle about some center of rotation. That center of rotation always is in line with the rear axle, and the radius of that circle is no smaller than some certain distance. $$ $$ A quarter plane is a 2D space that is bounded by two lines at right angles. A quadrant of a graph is an example of a quarter plane. $$ $$ Diagrams to help explain are forthcoming. $$ $$ I'll update with new numbers.

Comment: Impressive - Most carmakers supply their info sheet with curb to curb turning diameter. Hence, I believe I add the width of the car to the minimum radius and multiply by 2. (1.67m (w) + 6.6)*2=16.5 m curb to curb turning radius (ie diameter). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turning_radius

Comment: Now that was 2D and one obstacle - for those moving furniture up and down revolving staircases, narrow doorframes and halls- The even harder 3D version - How can you determine if the object will fit or not and also how to determine the optimal angulation of the object?

Comment: @Misha That's actually a current research topic in computing (one that I studied in grad school at Berkeley). So while it's a very interesting topic, it's too broad to discuss here in detail here. One method I find interesting is to create a 6 dimensional space (three directional three rotational), project the obstacles through the space, then offset the surfaces according to the projected width of the object in the orientation corresponding to the rotational coordinate. Then any path that does not intersect this 6 dimensional geometry will work for moving the object through the obstacles.

Comment: appreciate your effort. What is the name of this topic in computing?

Comment: @Misha I think the general field is *collision avoidance*. The extra dimensional spaces I described are called [configuration spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_space). Here is [a presentation on the combination](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~motionplanning/lecture/Chap3-Config-Space_howie.pdf) Note though, I didn't use this technique to solve this problem as this technique as presented can't handle restrictions to motion besides obstacles (like the rear tires can't slide sideways)

Comment: @Rick: Any idea how much of a research topic it was in 1987, when Douglas Adams write *Dirk Gently's Holistic Detective Agency*?  If memory serves (it was awhile ago) the title character was trying to use a computer program to figure out how to get his couch out of a hallway corner where it had been stuck for many years.

Comment: @supercat Yes, I found a paper on this topic from 1983, so I'm sure there was still research being done on this by '87.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just take the car for a test drive and see if it can make the turn?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11929)

Comment: @Wasabi - I won't argue, as it doesn't explicitly answer the question as asked.  But I do believe this answer is better than the accepted answer based on the wording of the question.  If the question was about designing a turn in a new parking garage, or designing cars to accomodate tight garages then the accepted answer is far better than this one.  But for a practical answer to a specific question by someone who wants to buy a car that will be able to make the turn in the garage, I believe the best engineering solution is to simply try it.  Easy solution and guaranteed result.

Answer (score 1):

Something important to consider is that if the corridor taking you down to the underground is narrower then the width of the way turning in, then there are certain sizes of cars that are able to go in but are unable to go out from the underground garage. So these cars can only go out in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

On average allow a circle with a diameter of 13m (Radius 6.5m) for a carriage driveway.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer with additional information such as explanations or sources for where you got this number.